# Datalab offers optional upgrade to 1.2.20180713 which does not exist in GitHub releases

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

Datalab was very slow to start today.  I was presented with the option to update datalab to version 1.2.20180713.  The "what's new" link beside the message was for GitHub [datalab releases](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/releases).  The datalab release page does not have a release for version 1.2.20180713.

Is 1.2.20180713 a legitimate datalab update?

[Datalab update message and GitHub datalab release page with missing version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNvCi.png)

Comment: This was answered on GitHub datalab issues.  https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/2044

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer on the GitHub datalab issues site.
https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/2044

1.2.20180713 is a release and the releases page was updated to show this version.